# Infinite loop when trying to read from Java Scanner inside an IO Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, io, io-monad, cats-effect

I was trying to do an exercise for a Cats Effect course in which I was required, among other things, to read a document line by line and wait a certain amount of time between lines.

The teacher's solution was the following:

```scala
def readLines(sc: Scanner): IO[Unit] =
  if sc.hasNextLine then IO(sc.nextLine).debug *> IO.sleep(1.second) *> readLines(sc)
  else IO.unit
```

However, I attempted to create a tail-recursive function from the same function above, and it looked something like this:

```scala
def readLines(sc: Scanner): IO[Unit] =

  @tailrec
  def tailReader(accum: IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] =

    if sc.hasNextLine then tailReader(accum *> IO(sc.nextLine).debug *> IO.sleep(1.second))
    else accum

  tailReader(IO.unit)

end readLines
```

The problem is, the first implementation does read line by line and finishes. On the other hand, my implementation never finishes and never reads even the first line of the document, and is then followed by an OutOfMemoryError.

My question is, is there any way to implement the first function in a way that is tail-recursive and purely functional?

I know there is a way to make the first implementation stack-safe by using the `>>` operator instead of the `*>` one. However that's not what I'm looking for, instead I'm looking to be able to use the `@tailrec` annotation.

The way I was able to partially fix the error was to create a value at the beginning of the function that saves the current line from the scanner, like this:

```scala
def readLines(sc: Scanner): IO[Unit] =

  @tailrec
  def tailReader(accum: IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] =

    val currentLine = sc.nextLine

    if sc.hasNextLine then tailReader(accum *> IO(currentLine).debug *> IO.sleep(1.second))
    else accum >> IO(currentLine).debug.void

  tailReader(IO.unit)

end readLines
```

Although this solved the problem, I am pretty sure that the solution is not purely functional.

I would be very grateful if you could give me a hand with this problem, I am just starting to understand the world of effects, and your help would come in handy!

For everything else, have a really nice day.

Comment: Two things, first your professor solution is wrong, `sc.hasNextLine` must be suspended in `IO`, second, why are you focused on using `tailrec`? There is no point in that.

Comment: I just wanted to do it as a mental gymastics exercise, no actual reason to do it other than practice the design pattern.

Also, thanks so much por the aclaration about `sc.hasNextLine`! It clearearly mutates some internal state. Thanks again!

Comment: It does not mutate internal state, rather it access / read some mutable state. Also, which design pattern you want to practice? Because, again, you don't write tail rec algorithms using `IO`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Also, I usually try to optimise algorithms using dynamic programming. And I have understood that optimising a function by making it tail-recursive overlaps with the previously mentioned technique. So that's why I was trying to make the function tail-recursive, just as an exercise. 

On the other hand, is there any reason not to do tail-recursive algorithms with IOs other than they are already implemented in a stack-safe way?

Comment: There is only one reason to write a tail-recursive algorithm, to avoid blowing up the stack. If the function is stack safe without being tail-recursive there is no need to complicar the code. Also, as you saw, trying to make it tail-recursive is very difficult and complicates the code. So, again, there is no reason for doing that. The number one reason to use `IO` is to increase the maintainability of the code, thus deliberately going against that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clarifications:

1. Regarding `>>` and `*>`:

```scala
  def *>[B](that: IO[B]): IO[B] =
    productR(that)

  def productR[B](that: IO[B]): IO[B] =
    flatMap(_ => that)

  def >>[B](that: => IO[B]): IO[B] =
    flatMap(_ => that)
```

2. You can do stack safe recursion with `flatMap` because of how [Monad](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html#tailrecm) is designed in Cats.

I'll swap `>>` and `*>` with `flatMap` in the following examples and drop `@tailrec` as stack safety is already guaranteed.

**Now what's wrong here**

```scala
def readLines(sc: Scanner): IO[Unit] = {

  def tailReader(accum: IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] = {
    if (sc.hasNextLine)
      tailReader { 
        accum
          .flatMap(_ => IO(sc.nextLine()))
          .flatMap(_ => IO.sleep(1.second))
      }
    else
      tailReader(accum)
  }

  tailReader(IO.unit)
}
```

We're checking `sc.hasNextLine` continually while not evaluating `sc.nextLine`.
`IO(sc.nextLine)` is only a description at this point, nothing is evaluated.

Make the recursive call part of the `flatMap` chain to solve this:

```scala
  def tailReader(accum: IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] = {
    if (sc.hasNextLine)
      IO(sc.nextLine())
        .flatMap(_ => IO.sleep(1.second))
        .flatMap(_ => tailReader(accum)) //make the call here
    else
      tailReader(accum)
  }
```

then there's another small issue with the recursive method.
`tailReader(..)` returns an IO only after it checks for next line once.

Use `IO.suspend` to completely separate definition from evaluation.

```scala
   def tailReader(accum: IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] = IO.suspend {
    if (sc.hasNextLine)
      IO(sc.nextLine())
        .flatMap(_ => IO.sleep(1.second))
        .flatMap(_ => accum)
    else
      tailReader(accum)
  }
```

Now `tailReader(IO.unit)` returns the IO without calling `hasNextLine` even once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the other recomendations! Now I understand a bit more why the function did not work in the first place. Have a nice day!